# Show that $\pi\mid_{D^2} : D^2 \to X\cup_f D^2$ is a quotient map

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, quotient-spaces

I want to prove the following:

> Let $f :\mathbb{S}^{n-1} \to X$ be continuous and surjective and let $\pi : D^n + X \to X\cup_f D^n$ be the canonical projection. Show that $\pi\mid_{D^n}: D^n \to X \cup_f D^n$ is a quotient map.

My guess is that since $f$ is continuous, we can invoke the universal property of quotient spaces to create a continuous function $\tilde{f} : X\cup_f D^n \to X$ such that $\tilde{f} = q \circ f$ where $q=\pi\mid_{D^n} = \pi \circ i$ and $i : D^n \to D^n + X$ is the inclusion map, but I'm been unable to complete the proof. I need to show that $q$ is surjective and that $q^{-1}(U)$ is open if and only if $U$ is open in $X\cup_f D^n$. One implication of this last part is done since both $\pi$ and $i$ are continuous, so it's the other implication where I need some help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does $D^n+X$ mean?

Comment: @AnonymousCoward Maybe it's a strange notation but it really means the disjoint union $D^n \coprod X$.

Comment: It's quite common, actually. The disjoint union is the coproduct (sum) in the category of topological spaces.

Comment: I'm not sure that the statement is actually true without some further assumptions.

Comment: @Tyrone In which particular assumptions are you thinking of?

Comment: Either on the map $f$ or the space $X$.

Comment: @Tyrone Maybe I could further assume that $X$ is Hausdorff, but I don't know if that changes anything...

Comment: What doex $\cup_f$ mean?

Comment: @WilliamElliot X\cup_f Y$ is the adjunction space.

Comment: @user313212, if $X$ is Hausdorff then $f$ is a quotient map since it is surjective and $S^{n-1}$ is compact. It's not difficult to then show that the pushout of a quotient map is again a quotient map (in this case the map $\pi$).